# autant à + infinitif + que ou aussi à + infinitif + que ?

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

Il est bien connu qu'à quelques nuances près, pour exprimer la comparaison on utilise *aussi* avec les adjectifs et les adverbes et *autant* dans les autres cas. Cependant j'ai des doutes sur la construction *à* + infinitif. Est-ce bel et bien *autant* qui devrait la précéder ?

À titre d'exemple:

> Les parents de cette adolescente sont **aussi** à blâmer pour son basculement dans la délinquance qu'elle-même.

> Les parents de cette adolescente sont **autant** à blâmer pour son basculement dans la délinquance qu'elle-même.

Laquelle de ces formulations est du français correct ?

Comment: Les deux sont correctes, le sens n'est pas le même, comme l'explique Toto.

Comment: @Frank Malgré le fait que la première phrase se termine également par _qu'elle_ ?

Comment: Je vais faire une réponse plus détaillée.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La locution corrélative « aussi à < verbe > que » se trouve très rarement, mais  on en trouve deux exemples pour « blâmer ».

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22aussi%20%C3%A0%20bl%C3%A2mer%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

- 1873 C'est vrai , avait dit Noël aux idées duquel cela s'ajustait parfaitement , mais vous êtes presqu'aussi à blâmer que lui
- 1982 Nous disons que ce sont les deux camps qui sont à blâmer ; il existe une interaction entre les deux camps et les Soviétiques sont tout aussi à blâmer que nous , car ce sont leurs bombes qui vont exploser chez nous.

Il est préférable d'utiliser la seconde forme (autant à < verbe > que ), qui est utilisée presque uniquement.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22autant%20%C3%A0%20bl%C3%A2mer%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: Could those who downvote leave a comment telling what is wrong? It is usual to explain what  you think is wrong, at least serious users do. That makes 3 answers downvoted in the time of a few hours and there is not a single comment for any one of them.

Answer (score 2):

La première phrase, avec *aussi*, signifie qu'ils doivent être blâmés eux aussi.

la deuxième, avec *autant*, signifie, non seulement qu'ils doivent être blâmés, mais, de plus, de la même façon, avec la même sévérité.

Comment: Mais c'est: **aussi...qu'elle-même**. Si tu veux garder le sens de "ils doivent être blâmés eux aussi", il vaut mieux enlever ce **qu'elle-même** à la fin, il n'est plus nécessaire, car il ne s'agit plus d'une comparaison.

Comment: Je crois que tu l'as enlevé inconsciemment pour passer au sens que tu donnes, mais pour ce sens que tu donnes le _qu'elle-même_ à la fin est inintelligible :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ce ***aussi*** et ce ***autant*** peuvent donner un sens différent aux deux phrases, avec une petite modification.

Si le sens escompté pour les deux phrases est que les parents sont à blâmer *dans la même mesure que l'adolescente* (une comparaison), alors la deuxième phrase, avect ***autant*** est la plus naturelle. La première phrase irrite l'oreille à tel point qu'on a envie de voir une erreur dans ce *qu'elle-même* final, et de l'enlever, pour rétablir la phrase suivante, dont le sens est maintenant bien différent:

> Les parents de cette adolescente sont **aussi** à blâmer pour son basculement dans la délinquance.

Cette phrase signifie que les parents sont à blâmer, de la même façon que quelqu'un ou quelque chose d'autre qui a déjà été mentionné dans le contexte, mais il ne s'agit plus d'une comparaison, on n'essaie pas de savoir dans quelle mesure ils sont à blâmer.

On peut aussi noter que la deuxième phrase serait également correcte sans le *qu'elle-même* final:

> Les parents de cette adolescente sont **autant** à blâmer pour son basculement dans la délinquance.

Dans ce cas, la comparaison est ambigüe, le lecteur doit inférer le deuxième côté de la comparaison, peut-être du contexte, mais cette phrase ne surprend pas et est intelligible si le context s'y prête.

Comment: Merci, je ne peux accepter qu'une seule réponse, mais la vôtre est tout aussi utile, je l'upvote.

Comment: @Vlad Pas de problème. En première lecture, je n'avais pas fait attention, et comme Toto, j'étais tombé dans le panneau, en attribuant un autre sens à ce _aussi_. C'est dire à quel point _aussi...qu'elle-même_ n'est plus courant dans l'usage :-)